# Click on image inside ArrayAdapter to remove item in listview

Tags: android, arraylist, fragment, adapter

I have Fragment...

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {...
```

which calls adapter...

```
    MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter...
    my.setAdapter(adapter);
```

adapter has image for delete item. I can listen image click but cannot remove item from listview which is in fragment.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {...

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {...

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // ???????????
        ...}
```

Comment: Simple remove object from data of adapter and call `notifyDatasetChnaged()` of adapter in `ImageView's onClick()`

Comment: How to access adapter?

Comment: You are in adapter class, simply call using `.this`

Comment: On imageView onClick to use "this"... I don't understand well. Sorry.

Comment: @Arnes your class `extends ArrayAdapter<String>`. you can use `MyArrayAdapter.this.notifyDatasetChnaged()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your click is inside an `OnClickListener` inner class you must specify `MyArrayAdapter.this` to access the functions of the adapter from inside the click listener. If you just use `this` you will be referring to the `OnClickListener` and will only have access to methods on that class.

Like so:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyArrayAdapter.this.remove(getItem(position));
            MyArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

Comment: this one crashes the app, also :(

Comment: 02-27 21:25:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(11332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:25:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(11332): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-27 21:25:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(11332):  at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
02-27 21:25:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(11332):  at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
02-27 21:25:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(11332):  at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:229)
02-27 21:25:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(11332):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.remove(ArrayAdapter.java:244)

Comment: It's probably because you initialize your adapter with an array ie: String[] instead of a list ie: ArrayList<String>. Without seeing the entire MyArrayAdapter constructor it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Has been a long time since I did Java, but as far I can remember you can use this:

```
this.remove(position);
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This is the current object, you are calling a static that might or might not be initialized yet, probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method inside your adapter:

```
private boolean removeItemByPosition(int position){
    try{
        items.remove(position);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }   
}
```

In some cases, id the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method doesn't work, try with re-setting the `ListView Adapter`, you shuould be able to do this inside the `Fragment`.

Answer (score -1):

simply call `convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`